# something wrong with class initing?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have a class "Hero",  subclassed from `CCSpriteBatchNode` (cocos2d):

```
@interface Hero : CCSpriteBatchNode {...}
```

I'm initing it like this:

```
Hero *hero;
...
hero = [[Hero alloc] initWithWorld:world];
```

Here is init method of `Hero`:

```
-(id) initWithWorld:(b2World*)world
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

Till this moment all works fine: I can add `hero` as a child to my layer, and it will be displayed correctly. But then, I'm trying to get some data from `hero`. I have this method in `Hero` class:

```
-(b2Body*) getBody; //in Hero.h

-(b2Body*) getBody  //in Hero.mm
{
    return selfBody;
}
```

and my application crashes just after calling `[hero getBody];` with error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CCSpriteBatchNode getBody]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x42bde0'

so, he tries to find method `getBody` in `CCSpriteBatchNode` class. offcorse, he cant find it there. But **WHY** he tries to find it there? Why not in `Hero` class?
P.S. all my classes are `*.mm`. I need it to support box2d.

### EDIT

The ony time I use `hero` between initing and calling `getBody` is adding it to `CCLayer`:

```
[self addChild:hero z:0 tag:kTagParentNode]; //self - CCLayer subclass
```

`getBody` is called from `tick` method:

```
[self schedule:@selector(tick:)];

...

-(void)tick:(float)dt 
{
    CGPoint scaledVelocity = ccpMult(leftJoystick.velocity, 480.0f);
    if (scaledVelocity.y > CGPointZero.y)
    {

        [objectControls jump:[hero getBody]];

    }
    if (scaledVelocity.x > CGPointZero.x) 
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the exact code between the point where you create the Hero object and you call `[hero getBody]`

Comment: tnx for responce. I added what you asked. see edited question.

Comment: did you try it with `[objectControls jump:[(Hero*)hero getBody]];`

Comment: tnx for responce. I tryed it before, and did it agane just now. I got same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's hard to tell what's causing the issue without seeing much code, I advise you to rethink your architecture.

A `CCSpriteBatchNode` is an object that's used by the cocos2d engine to render batched sprites. Is your `Hero` really such an object? I don't think so. The Hero should be a class on it's own and have a `has one` relation to a `CCSpriteBatchNode` and a `b2Body`.

Why? There are several reasons for this. First and foremost it's going to decouple your `Hero` implementation from the interface imposed by cocos2d. If the creators of cocos2d decide to change some implementation details, your class might no longer work if it inherits from a `CCNode`. Also think about encapsulation: Does a visual component really have to know about player logic?

If you split up your architecture you're going to make your code better readable, easier to maintain and also easier to port to another platform if that's ever going to happen. For a similar post, see [this question on gamedev.SE.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20818/cocos2d-composition-using-ccspritebatchnode/20819)

Comment: tnx for response. I need some time to rethink my architecture, I think I got it.